# Selenium Python: Repeat for bucle and when finish, go to next page and start again

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**[Solved]**

Hi I have a for loop to scrap some data in a list, but list continue some more pages, so I want to insert a click and go to next page when list is completed, and repeat, until last page

```
    base=[]
    for product in products: 
   
      product.click()
      info=driver.find_element(By.Xpath,'asdfsd').text
      time.sleep(1)
      list={'Info':info}
      base.append(list)
      driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
      time.sleep(2)
```

Ok so I got the solution for this with a while true, I share it:

**[Solution]**

```
base=[]
while True:
   products=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'asdfs')
   for product in products:
      product.click()
      info=driver.find_element(By.Xpath,'asdfsd').text
      time.sleep(1)
      list={'Info':info}
      base.append(list)
      driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
      time.sleep(2)
   try:
      nextpage=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'assfasd')
      nextpage.click()
      time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue/error? Which line? Which error?

Comment: No, I just want to add a condition "when the loop finish, click "next page" and start again. I don't know how to do it